# Android: вывод кнопок на экран

Tags: java, android

Создал класс, который создает множество кнопок. Вот так:

```
//Class test
public class test {

Button test1;

public void init(Context context){
    test1 = new Button(context);

}
//Class Activity
public class WorkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      Button button;
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work);
    test test1 = new test();
    button = new Button(this);
    test1.init(this);

}
```

Кнопки как бы созданы, но как их вывести в активность?

Comment: добавляйте их через разметку activity_work.xml там же проще, или вам нужно именно в коде создать?

Comment: цель - вынести код с созданием кнопок в другой класс, что бы в mainActivity они создавались вызовом test1.init(); там будет массив кнопок(как будто дни календаря).

Answer (score 1):

Можно например так:

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.activity_work_layout_id);

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

layout.addView(button);
```

Comment: это же вставлять в onCreate?

Comment: ну можно и туда, но вообще в то место, где хотите